# SQL to get the elapsed time for Jobs

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table contains transaction time, 1 batch will trigger several jobs. I want to add the time elapsed in each job for the batch.
The transaction tables's format is as follows,

```
START_TIME          JOB END_TIME
1/7/2012 12:10:24   AA  1/7/2012 12:18:49
1/7/2012 12:10:23   AA  1/7/2012 12:10:23
1/7/2012 12:10:24   AA  1/7/2012 12:10:24
7/7/2012 16:10:33   AA  7/7/2012 16:15:23
7/7/2012 16:10:32   AA  7/7/2012 16:10:32
7/7/2012 16:10:33   AA  7/7/2012 16:10:33
7/7/2012 17:58:21   BB  7/7/2012 19:05:41
7/7/2012 16:40:25   BB  7/7/2012 16:40:25
7/7/2012 17:56:58   BB  7/7/2012 17:56:58
1/7/2012 14:00:11   BB  1/7/2012 14:47:09
1/7/2012 12:40:19   BB  1/7/2012 12:40:19
1/7/2012 13:58:33   BB  1/7/2012 13:58:33
```

What I want to achieve is,

```
DATE       JOB    TIME SPENT
1/7/2012   AA     ADDING THE TIME SPENT for AA on 1/7/2012
7/7/2012   AA     ADDING THE TIME SPENT for AA on 7/7/2012
1/7/2012   BB 
7/7/2012   BB
```

May I know what SQL can do the expected result?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `START_TIME` and `END_TIME` are both `DATE` data types (rather than `TIMESTAMP` or `VARCHAR2`) and assuming that either the `START_TIME` and `END_TIME` are always on the same day (i.e. it can't start late on 1/7 and finish early on 1/8)

```
SELECT trunc(start_time), 
       job, 
       sum( end_time - start_time ) total_time_in_days
  FROM your_table
 GROUP BY trunc(start_time), job
 ORDER BY job, trunc(start_time)
```

The total will be expressed in days.  If you would rather get an `INTERVAL` back

```
SELECT trunc(start_time), 
       job, 
       sum( numtodsinterval( end_time - start_time, 'day' ) ) elapsed_interval
  FROM your_table
 GROUP BY trunc(start_time), job
 ORDER BY job, trunc(start_time)
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply.. actually I don't know it 's a timestamp type or not, I just get the data in excel. Could I import it into MYSQL and do the calculation?

Comment: @IvanChan - You tagged the question with the SQL and Oracle tags.  But now you're saying that you don't have an Oracle database, you instead have an Excel spreadsheet with data in it?  You undoubtedly could load the spreadsheet data into a database.  But if you load the data into something other than Oracle, the queries you'd need to run would be different.

Comment: OK, the data is stored in Oracle, but someone extract data to excel but i don't have oracle DB in hand. Thanks!

Comment: @IvanChan - What does "I don't have Oracle DB in hand" mean to you?  Does that mean that you cannot access the Oracle database and that you can't ask someone to run the query for you?  If you want to start with the data in an Excel spreadsheet, I'll delete my answer and edit your question to reflect that fact.

Comment: No, I will try to test tomorrow morning , thanks for your great answer!